# Почему приходит неполная станица при иcпользовании curl + proxy?

Tags: php, http, curl, proxy

Знатоки протокола HTTP, помогите с проблемой!

Использую curl (в PHP) через прокси (доступа к прокси нет) для получения контента сайта (прокси HTTP). Очень часто приходят страницы неполные, обрываются на полутеге (например

```
...<p class="myclas
```

дальше контент заканчивается). Закономерностей когда и как оборвется контент нет. Притом если получать не через прокси - проблемы нет. Искал решения в интернете, находил следующие варианты решений:

1. Версию curl обновлял до 7.36 - не помогло.
2. Отправлял заголовок "Expect: " - не помогло.
3. Таймаут ставил в 0 - не помогло.
4. Выставлял опцию `CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION` в `CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0` - если ответ приходит формате HTTP 1.1 то все равно обрывается.
5. Получал контент в обход `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER = 1` через `ob_start` и так далее - не помогло.
6. `CURLOPT_HTTP_TRANSFER_DECODING = 0` и `CURLOPT_HTTP_CONTENT_DECODING = 0` - не помогло.

Если включать режим `VERBOSE` в `curl`, то на проблемных страницах пишет

> ...
>
> nread <= 0, server closed connection, bailing
>
> curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
>
> ...

Также проблема наблюдается только при `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`. Наблюдается на очень многих сайтах.

Как все-таки получить контент полностью, или, если это невозможно, как определить что контент пришел неполный?

Answer (score 1):

Определить размер ответа:

```
$proxy = "IP:PORT"; // задаем адрес прокси-сервера
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070208');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);    
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch); // получаем информацию о HTTP-ответе
var_dump($info);
```

`header_size`  - размер заголовка;

`size_download` и `download_content_length` - должны совпадать.

Comment: download_content_length равен -1 при Transfer-Encoding: chunked, так как заранее неизвестно какой длинны будет контент - в этом то вся и проблема(((